# How to order fields on the inspected object alphabetically?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In chrome devtools, it used to be that when you console.log object or hovered over a variable while debugging or when you inspected object in any other way fields were displayed in alphabetical order. Recent update changed the order and now it's undefined (in my head at least, maybe there is some ordering to it). How do you display fields alphabetically like before ?

Comment: It's fixed already in the upcoming Chrome so you can temporarily switch to using Chrome Canary.